# How to save posted image in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I try in different to save picture Type `String` on my database but it always gives me `System.Web.HttpPostedFileWrapper`. I dont understand what's wrong here

I want to create a new Product containing title,description,*image*,and their category. When I post data via create it saves data but does not display *image* and when I check database picture field I find value of image is `HttpPostedFileWrapper` not p.png or product.jpg –

**This is controller:**

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[Route("Create")]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Ida,description,image,Userid,Idc,titre")] Article article,HttpPostedFileBase postedFile)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (postedFile != null)
        {
            var a =new byte[postedFile.ContentLength] ;
            article.image = Convert.ToBase64String(a);
            postedFile.InputStream.Read(a, 0, postedFile.ContentLength);
        }

        db = new IdentityDBEntities2();
        // Add article to database  
        article.UserId = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId();
        article.Idc = Convert.ToInt32(Request["Idc"]);

        db.Articles.Add(article);
        ViewBag.Idcc = new SelectList(db.Categories, "Id", "libelle");
        db.SaveChanges();                
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(article);
}
```

Comment: please try to elaborate your problem a little bit. What is "picture"? What exactly are you trying to do? Also, please note that article.image is always either an empty byte array converted to a string or its default value.

Comment: hello picture is image on database and i want to display image on ~/Content/img folder .

Comment: If your "edit" is a working solution, please move it to an answer below. This helps make it clearer what part of your text is a question, and what part is a self-answer.

Comment: ok brother   thanks for notice that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ***postedfile*** parameter is a **HttpPostedFileBase**-type parameter. You must save the fully qualified name of the file on the client instead of saving this parameter directly. Try this:

```
article.image = postedFile.FileName;
```

Comment: i'm already do that before and try to saveas file but doesn't work bro

Comment: Can you explain in a specific way what you want to do?

Comment: Ok brother I want create new `Product` containt title,description,picture,and their category when i post data via create is save data but not display image and when i check database picture field i find value of image is `HttpPostedFileWrapper ` not p.png or product.jpg

Comment: You want to save the file in the database as "file name.file extension". If so, would you please try the code above?

Comment: yes i try it but is doen't work brother can you edit respense with my code thanks brother

Comment: If so, what you want to do is different. Because the code I wrote above is a code that works on my project. If you want to do something different than the one I explained above, please share more information.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/dotnet/api/system.web.httppostedfilebase.filename?view=netframework-4.7.2 And take a look at this.

Comment: Doesn't work brother please can you contact me on my facebook ?? ill show you all detail    Badr Sen . Email:Morad28138@gmail.com . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You want just to copy a file? Why not use:

```
System.IO.File.Copy("source", "destination");
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6cfw35a.aspx

Comment: Yes i want just get value of file for exemple   product.png and save it on picture field on database as string

Comment: See my next comment

Answer (score 0):

Please change to this, move line of code reading from stream up

```
 if (postedFile != null)
                {
                    var a = new byte[postedFile.ContentLength];
                    postedFile.InputStream.Read(a, 0, postedFile.ContentLength);
                    article.image = Convert.ToBase64String(a);

                }
```

Updated:

I tried to reproduce source code in my side, it worked well.

Did you setup `new {enctype="multipart/form-data"}` for your form?

```
[HttpPost]
        //[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Ida,description,image,Userid,Idc,titre")] Article article, HttpPostedFileBase postedFile)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (postedFile != null)
                {
                    var a = new byte[postedFile.ContentLength];
                    postedFile.InputStream.Read(a, 0, postedFile.ContentLength);
                    article.image = Convert.ToBase64String(a);

                    //db = new IdentityDBEntities2();
                    //// Add article to database  
                    //article.UserId = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId();
                    //article.Idc = Convert.ToInt32(Request["Idc"]);

                    //db.Articles.Add(article);
                    //ViewBag.Idcc = new SelectList(db.Categories, "Id", "libelle");
                    //db.SaveChanges();
                    TempData["Image"] = article.image;
                }
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(article);
        }
```

Create.cshtml file

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("Create","Feedback",FormMethod.Post,new {enctype="multipart/form-data"}))
{

    <input type="file" name="postedFile"/>

    <input type="submit" value="Save"/>
}
```

Index.cshtml file

```
@{
    var imgSrc = string.Format("data:image/gif;base64,{0}", TempData["Image"]);
}
<img src="@imgSrc"/>
```

Comment: Doen't work brother is stay save HttpPostedFileWrapper in image field

Comment: Can you change article image to byte[] and remove Convert.ToBase64String ?

Comment: When i change image to byte is hide input file for i upload file  this is my razor input                    `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.image, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @type = "file" ,@name= "postedFile" ,@id= "postedFile" } })`

Answer (score 0):

Just an update. I used varbinary in the end. I added the image to the database by using

```
if (fileExtension.ToLower() == ".jpg" || fileExtension.ToLower() == ".png")
        {
            Stream stream = postedFile.InputStream;
            BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(stream);
            byte[] imgByte = reader.ReadBytes((int)stream.Length);
            con = new SqlConnection("MyConnectionString");
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Events (AspNetUsersId,EvtName,EvtType,EvtDescription,EvtDate,EvtVote, EvtImage) values (@AspNetUsersId, @EvtName, @EvtType, @EvtDescription, @EvtDate, @EvtVote, @EvtImage)", con);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AspNetUsersId", userId);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EvtName", eventName.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EvtType", eventType.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EvtDescription", eventDescription.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EvtDate", datetimepicker.Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EvtVote", 0);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@EvtImage", SqlDbType.VarBinary).Value = imgByte;
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
        }
```

And displayed it in an image tag by using

```
byte[] imgByte = null;
        con = new SqlConnection("MyConnectionString");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Events", con);
        con.Open();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(ds);
        foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            imgByte = (byte[])(dr["EvtImage"]);
            string str = Convert.ToBase64String(imgByte);
            imageTest.Src = "data:Image/png;base64," + str;
        }
```

Front-End code:

```
<img runat="server" id="imageTest" src="imageIDtagName" />
```

Thanks for everyone's help !